Trying to make a connection to Keycloak with Nodejs
i´m trying to connect my app to a keycloak server, but i can´t seem to make it right.
I would be happy if anybody could help.
My config file:
const Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');
const session = require('express-session');
const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

let config = {
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: memoryStore,
    serverUrl: 'http://localhost:8666', 
    auth_callback: "https://keycloak.integration.impacta.social/realms/myRealm",
    realmPublicKey: "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAqCKTmch6VuCd4mHf8FHlIAHUv7w+eIyHn41KJhKwVChleSopAZOHAyx1M4+W68a1ZdvlImkIfWaVJhPg+84ZQROghIusnjKezT2kfss3qUCsJzfiv6EW/3d9DwQ38hrwkHRGaG8NXuxz2bUv5s3tAPsbJB/HPLDBx6W8uOFIpVOlrBH7LWvYtTWvIvleueTBkFan2jWHEzlfu608M+8BRQaur7Be1YLYRsJtcSPllsoQ7t1ZKZYV5LhzUrxheCpt+bA/RDeUkG5qchyc1eMWvYH1kXzv8SvU5wFaD5eTSFIT05dScJOv3ooKM/n+PhSW+YyfK4u8N6eRAXbBMVdt4QIDAQAB",
    scope: "EDA-dedicated",
    clientId: 'EDA', 
    secret: 'D84FoxVeBkP5YiOQdOTC6nFQgDEtueEQ',
    bearerOnly: true, 
    realm: 'myRealm' 
}

module.exports = new Keycloak({
    store: memoryStore,
}, config);

the app file (only the calling to the config part):
 const keycloak = require('./middleware/keycloak/keycloak-config'); // Keycloak
    this.app.use(keycloak.middleware());

and the router:
       const router = require('express').Router();
    const keycloak = require("./keycloak-config");

//auth login

    router.get('/', [keycloak.protect()], (req,res) => {
      res.send("hi 1")
    });

When making the call, i´m using postman. After introducing the bearer token that Keycloak provides, it always takes me to a:
{
    "status": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
}

Any clue?
Thank you.
